# PHP code to convert MySQL table not working

Tags: php, mysql

Limited knowledge MySQL user here. I have run the following PHP code to convert some data in my MySQL table, but it does not seem to be working:

```
<?php
include("../minimum_init.php");

/* Convert existing buddy_ban_table to user userid as key */

$bbrecs = $osDB->getAll('select * from ! ',array(BUDDY_BAN_TABLE) );
foreach ($bbrecs as $bbrec) {
    if (is_int(trim($bbrec['userid']) ) ) {
        $userid = $bbrec['userid'];
    } else {
        $userid = $osDB->getOne('select id from ! where username = ?',array(USER_TABLE, $bbrec['userid']) );
    }
    if (is_int(trim($bbrec['ref_userid'] )) ) {
        $ref_userid = $bbrec['ref_userid'];
    } else {
        $ref_userid = $osDB->getOne('select id from ! where username = ?',array(USER_TABLE, $bbrec['ref_userid']) );
    }
    if ($userid > 0 and $ref_userid > 0) {
        $osDB->query('update ! set userid=?, ref_userid=? where id=?', array(BUDDY_BAN_TABLE, $userid, $ref_userid, $bbrec['id']) );
    }
}
echo("Update process of buddy_ban table Complete<br />");
/* Update process of buddy_ban table Complete */
?>
```

The problem is that I am updating to the latest version of the software and it now calls to a `xxx_buddy_ban_list` table that has `userid` and `ref_userid` columns instead of the `username` and `ref_username` columns that the old version had.

I assume this code is supposed to convert the usernames to the userid's by getting the data from the `xxx_user` table which contains the columns titled `username` and `id` for each member on my website. However, when I open the page with this code it displays the message "Update process of buddy_ban table Complete" but nothing in the database has changed.

The code was included in the software update zip package. I have posted the question on the forum there, but no answer. The software has mostly been abandoned now so there are only a few active people in the forum.

Here's an excerpt from `var_dump($bbrecs)`:

```
array(14227) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(6) "188426"
        ["username"]=>
        string(15) "mykindawife"
        ["act"]=>
        string(1) "F"
        ["ref_username"]=>
        string(8) "polrave"
        ["act_date"]=>
        string(10) "1386057016"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(6) "188425"
        ["username"]=>
        string(8) "verner"
        ["act"]=>
        string(1) "H"
        ["ref_username"]=>
        string(6) "Ybang"
        ["act_date"]=>
        string(10) "1386049839"
    }
...
```

Comment: Do you have two `BUDDY_BAN_TABLE` tables? An old version with data and a new version with the new column names, but no data?

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for your help. I renamed the columns to userid and ref_userid before I ran the code. When I ran it before I still had the old headings in the table. This time It worked!!!!! Thank You, your question led me to the answer.

Comment: That's where I was headed. Just wasn't sure if we should alter the table columns or change the value of `BUDDY_BAN_TABLE`.

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer so new visitors can easily see it's been resolved. In two days, you can then mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the columns to userid and ref_userid before I ran the code. When I ran it before I still had the old headings in the table. This time It worked!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Using Mysql API

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $logon_ts = adConvert($row['lastlogh']);
  mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET lastlogon = '$logon_ts' WHERE tag='$row[tag]'");
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer to OP's question?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.